# MS Access 2007 reference subform control on tabbed control returning null

Tags: ms-access, controls, subforms

I have a subform reference returning Null where the textbox has a value in it. The code I am using is:

```
End Date: [Forms]![ReportCentre]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtEndDate]
```

This is in a tabbed control, but I could not find the .Pages property referred to in a similar question.

The subform being referenced is [LODForm], and the tab control (page area) is [NavigationSubform]

Why is this returning Null?

Answer (score 0):

The subform belongs to the form, not the tab control. The tab control only hides/displays other controls. And you will reference the subform control, not the subform. Thus:

```
End Date: [Forms]![ReportCentre]![NameOfYourSubformControl].[Form]![txtEndDate]
```

Inserted name of subform control:

```
End Date: [Forms]![ReportCentre]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtEndDate]
```

Comment: I suspect that's what I'm doing - i put a button on the subform with the code attached: MsgBox Me.Parent.ActiveControl.Name

This outputted NavigationSubform. Any other ideas then about why the query returns null?

Comment: Perhaps the record isn't saved.

Comment: As a follow up, I've noticed that subform knows the txtbox has a value. msgBox Me.txtEndDate returns expected results